# How do you make an animation run on the first onclick and stop on the second onclick (and so on) with JS/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, onclick

I'm just playing around with animations and couldn't work out how to make the outline flash once the div had been clicked, and when clicked again, stop flashing. Then when it is clicked again start flashing again and so on. My javascript clearing isn't working! Please help!!
CSS:

```
    #div5 {
                border:solid 5px lightblue;
                outline:solid 5px black;
                text-align:center;
            }
            @keyframes flash {
                50% {outline-color:yellow;}
            }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="div5">
            <h3>WARNING! <br> DO NOT CLICK!</h3>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
    var clicked = false
    document.getElementById("div5").onclick = function() {
                    if clicked = false {
                    document.getElementById("div5").style.animation = "flash 0.2s 
                    infinite"
                    clicked = true
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("div5").style.animation = "none"
                    }
                }
```

Comment: That's not JS, or too much syntax errors ...

Comment: Why not just toggle a class with that animation attached?

Comment: Eeh, shouldn't you set your "clicked"  variable back to false in your else clause?

Comment: `if clicked = false {` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your JS.

Firstly, it should be
`if (clicked === false)`

Secondly, you should add `clicked = false` in your else block to make it toggle.